# Combining coverage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a sql table with people and their coverage periods. Many people have multiple entries, and these should be condensed only where the coverage is continuous. The values are varchars but I can change to something else.

```
Name    effective   termination
John    20160101    20160315
John    20160316    20160501
John    20160601    20161101
John    20160701    20160731
John    20160801    20161231
```

Should be

```
John    20160101    20160501
John    20160601    20161231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea.  Identify where each group of coverage begins.  Use this information to identify the groups.  Then aggregation gets what you want:

```
  select name, min(effective) as effective, max(termination) as termination
  from (select t.*,
               sum(case when tprev.name is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by effective) as grp
        from t left join
             t tprev
             on t.name = tprev.name and
                t.effective = dateadd(day, 1, tprev.termination)
       ) t
  group by name, grp;
```